# How to find both control and left button clicked on mousemove in MFC

Tags: mfc

How to find both control and left button clicked events on mouse move in MFC?

Currently I'm using following lines to check whether control and `leftbutton` is down `onMouseMove()`
`GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)` && `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)`

But I understand we can check using `nFlags` in `OnMouseMove()`. Please let me know.

Comment: *"But I understand we can check using `nFlags` in `OnMouseMove()`."* - Yes, `nFlags` in a [CWnd::OnMouseMove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3158baat.aspx) override carries modifier key state information. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned the `nFlags` parameter, so simply check like this:

```
void CYourWnd::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // if CTRL is held and left mouse button is down ...
    if ((nFlags & MK_CONTROL) && (nFlags & MK_LBUTTON))
    {
        // ... do what you want here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps.